# Regex for ignoring cases

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering about creating regex for this situation.
for example Ive got these lines.

```
char * a
char    * a
char *a
 2 * 2
2*2
```

After use of regex, the matches should be`2 * 2` and `2*2`

I have tried for ignoring "chars" this one, but it doesn't work for more white space due to fixed length.

```
/(?<!char(\s))\*/
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Lines that doesn't contain alphabets? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to eliminate lines which contains *, but only in case that before * is char

Comment: Are these strings in separate lines. Can there there be `char    * a 3 * 3` also? And how do you want to handle that case?

Comment: so `^char\s+\*.*$`  ?

Comment: yes, they are separated

Answer (score 0):

**You can avoid using lookbehind as it prohibits using variable length string in it.** Since strings are in separate line you can use `/m` flag for MULTILINE switch.

Try this regex:

```
'/^(?!char +\*).*$/m'
```